# How to view every line execution in turbo c++

Tags: turbo-c++

I am using an old compiler which is turbo c++. I want to run every line one by one and examine them. My staff once did it with some shortcut. But i didn't asked how. please help me step over my code.

Answer (score 3):

Press `F-7` key. Then in `Menu -> Window -> Watch`. One new `Window` open. Press `Enter` in that `Window` take variables. Press `F-7`. You can see your program execution line by line.

[image]

Comment: You have to press F-7 each time to see the execution of every line. until program finish..

Comment: Thanks for your solution. It works for me. It shows the execution step by step. But I need to verify step by step execution after I got output. Your solution in only during execution. Please help me with this.

Comment: But what is the difference to verify output after getting output and before getting output? I think in both ways you getting output and execute each step.

Comment: See I need to know how the program was executed for getting such o/p. I mean first I have to compile and run the program. Then I have to check step by step , how each and every instruction was executed producing corresponding output. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to *trace* your program, there used to be an old UNIX tool `ctrace` (see for example this [manpage](http://www-it.desy.de/cgi-bin/man-cgi?ctrace%201)) that instrumented a C program with `printf()` statements after each line thus letting it print the trace as it runs. Otherwise, you might script the debugger (in UNIX/Linux at least) to print the line after each step).

Comment: turbo c++ is a DOS program, not UNIX

Comment: It's best if you don't post an answer to topics about which you have no knowledge.

Comment: `ctrace` is written in ANSI C and is easily portable to MS-DOS.

Comment: If you are going to suggest to a dos user that he compile a unix utility you probably need to give a link to the source.  Not all dos people know where to go to get unix program source just like not all unix users would know where to get as400 rpg program source.

Comment: Agreed. Looks like it is no longer widely available.

Comment: I found this: https://community.oracle.com/thread/2021333?start=0&tstart=0